# Do you have to be mark the changes when modifying code under MIT, Apache2.0 or BSD?

Tags: mit, apache-2.0, bsd, source-code

I'm currently programming a Flutter mobile app and a website.
I use code from the MIT license on the website and the app. In the app I also use code under the Apache 2.0 license and the BSD 3 clause.
I am modifying all of these codes. Some more and some less.

Is it allowed, if I have the licenses and copyright notices correctly in my project, **NOT** to add a comment or mark the modifications that I made?

*This question relates to all 3 licenses*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add e.g. "(c) 2021 Joe R. User" to the file headers (where you find such comments) to mark that you've made some changes, and claim your rights to them formally.

Check the licenses. They don't ask to mark any changes you do, so you don't have to do so.

But think of your gentle reader, a few years down the road and half a world distant (or even yourself, in a few weeks ;-): You want them to understand what is going on, perhaps do some changes in a different way or elide them altogether. Today presumably you keep the code under some version control system like `git` or `hg`.  Make small, self-contained changes (not "weekly dump of changes"), write clear commit messages (not "Updated", "New version"), perhaps add in a `Changelog` file with an overview of changes. Import any upstream packages marking their origin, version and so on clearly. If you update the base package, mark any relevant import commits clearly as such.

Think of any would-be user: Make sure to chase down any licenses that apply, record your findings and keep copies of the licenses at hand. This is also important for your protection: it isn't fun to get sued for inadvertently violating some license or software patent.

Comment: Yes, but you should or must indicate *that* you made changes; doing so in the copyright notice is one way and suffices. Yet without any indication whatsoever, the original authors might have recourse that you mis-represent their work and slander their good name, if you distribute modified code without indicating in any way *that* you modified it.

Comment: I think that you are not obliged to indicate your own copyright and therefore I think that it would be enough to mark the changed code snippets. If you would keep the code closed source you don't have to do any of that, right?

Comment: @VincentMusk, wether the code is open for all to see or closed doesn't really matter in much of my advise: *somebody* will have to make sense of it all later on. Most of the time that will be **you** ("You wrote it, so you'd be in the best position to..."), do yourself a huge favour. (Yes, that I learned the hard way,)

Comment: But I don’t have to do that.

Comment: @planetmaker You say that you "must" indicate that you made changes. I don't see that in the license text.

Comment: @VincentMusk it's not so much a requirement from the license itself rather than that you must not mis-represent what other people did. And if you made changes without indicating that it is a modified version, the previous authors might not want to be made responsible for what you did - what they would be held for, if there is no indication that there are additions which they did not make. If no indication of changes having happend is required, you could take any copyright notice and attach it to a piece of malicious software and claim it's a derivative of whatever.

Comment: When I have a general Copyright notice at the bottom of e.g. a Website that should be enough, right?